# Get specific XML data using C#

Tags: c#, xml

```
<hashtable>
    <entry>
        <string>recsonpage</string>
        &gt;
        <string>1</string>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <string>recsindb</string>
        <string>1</string>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <string>1</string>
        <hashtable>
            <entry>
                <string>orders.orderid</string>
                <string>84344969</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>entity.customerid</string>
                <string>19421067</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>entity.entityid</string>
                <string>84344969</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>orders.autorenew</string>
                <string>false</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>orders.endtime</string>
                <string>1572414460</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>orders.resellerlock</string>
                <string>false</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>orders.timestamp</string>
                <string>2018-10-30 05:47:41.791511+00</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>orders.customerlock</string>
                <string>true</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>entity.entitytypeid</string>
                <string>87</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>entity.currentstatus</string>
                <string>Active</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>entitytype.entitytypekey</string>
                <string>dotco</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>orders.transferlock</string>
                <string>true</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>orders.creationtime</string>
                <string>1540878460</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>orders.privacyprotection</string>
                <string>false</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>entitytype.entitytypename</string>
                <string>.CO Domain Name</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>orders.creationdt</string>
                <string>1540878459</string>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <string>entity.description</string>
                <string>testlbapi.co</string>
            </entry>
        </hashtable>
    </entry>
</hashtable>
```

Hi All. I need help on how to get the data of orders.orderid, entity.description of this XML Data. I used XElement but it gets the whole content of this XML Data. Any idea on this? Thank you in advance. Hi All. I need help on how to get the data of orders.orderid, entity.description of this XML Data. I used XElement but it gets the whole content of this XML Data. Any idea on this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @IrisLorrenHequibal, please, do not repeat your message just to get rid of SO warnings, instead try to provide more information, so that your chances of getting help will be higher!

Comment: You already asked the same thing about *JSON*. This XML schema is actually harder to query than a JSON file. What are you trying to do? Why not use proper elements and attributes instead of dumping a hashtable into unordered XML? A useful XML schema would be `<entity><orders/><entityType/></entity>`.

Comment: This sounds like [an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem with X and assume the solution is Y. When that doesn't work, you ask about Y, not X. In this case you assume that X will be solved by changing how you serialize unordered data. What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Where does this data come from? A database? Another system? Why not create proper objects to model it and serialize it to XML or JSON?

Comment: it's coming from an API URL.

Comment: Pretty printed the xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an `XElement root` representing the whole tree, you can iterate over the entries:

```
foreach (var entry in root.Elements("entry")
{
    ...
}
```

Each entry seems to have two sub-elements: one `<string>key</string>` and another `<type>...</type>` (where type can be string or hashtable).

To get the key string, you could use

```
var key = entry.Elements().First().Value;
```

For the value, you have to discriminate according to the element name:

```
var valueElement = entry.Elements().ElementAt(1);
if (valueElement.Name == "string")
{
    var value = valueElement.Value;
}
else if (valueElement == "hashtable")
{
    // here, you have to recurse with valueElement instead of root
}
```

EDIT: Shorter way to get only value of orders.orderid:

```
var orderIdElement = root.Descendants("entry").FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Elements().First().Value == "orders.orderid");
var orderId = orderIdElement .Elements().ElementAt(1).Value;
```

Comment: but my question is how will I only get the content of orders.orderid and entity.description on the XML data I provided?

Comment: Added this special case to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function to fetch specific sibling element text.

```
public string ExtractNodeValue(XDocument doc, string search)
{
    var result = doc.Descendants("entry")
                    .Where(x => x.Elements().ElementAt(0).Value == search)
                    .Select(i => (string)i.Elements().ElementAt(1).Value)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

    return result;
}
```

And you can use above function like

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"Url to xml file");

string orderId = ExtractNodeValue(doc, "orders.orderid");
string description = ExtractNodeValue(doc, "entity.description");

string output = "orders.orderid: " + orderId + "\nentity.description: " + description;
```

**Output from Debugger:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried your code but ExtractNodeValue can't be recognized in string orderID and string description.

Comment: @IrisLorrenHequibal, this is an exception? then please paste exception message so I'll try to resolve it

Comment: @IrisLorrenHequibal, If answer was help you then mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green :)